# Compiled script with justpy doesn't work - [WinError 3] The system cannot find

Tags: python, compilation, justpy

I use justpy in my program, but it doesn't work after compilation.
When I execute the binary I am still getting error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

So I created brand new project with sample from this page: https://justpy.io/tutorial/getting_started/

```
import justpy as jp

def hello_world():
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    jp.Hello(a=wp)
    return wp

jp.justpy(hello_world)
```

It works when I run it from pycharm or from cmdline as script.

Then I used **auto-py-to-exe** or **pyinstaller **--onefile main.py, to create EXE file.
(pyinstaller output: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.)
In both cases, when I run the binary file, it ended up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\GitHub2\rozne\chessResults_1\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import justpy as jp
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "justpy\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "justpy\justpy.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "jpcore\justpy_app.py", line 68, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: **[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified**: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI315082/justpy/templates\\js\\vue'
[27424] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Python 3.9.7
justpy 0.13.0

Can you give me a hint, what is the reason ? thanks